# Store value entry with tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I got a problem storing values that entry in a pop up window created with Tkinter. When I write the value in the text field and try to save it in a variable with get() (x=variable.get()), x doesn't take the value, instead take zero value I don't know why, but  when I try to do this in IPhyton it works perfectly.
This is a piece of my code:

```
root = Tk()

root.title("PARÁMETROS MORFOMÉTRICOS DE LA CUENCA")

root.geometry("450x360")

NC_label = Label(root, text = "Número de curva:")

NC_label.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

NC_Int = IntVar()

NC_entry = Entry(root, textvariable = NC_Int)

NC_entry.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

numcur=NC_Int.get()

ok = Button(root, text = "OK",  command = root.destroy)

ok.grid(row = 2, column = 2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are calling `NC_Int.get()` about one millisecond after you create the widget. You are going to have to type really, really fast.

Comment: Have you tried using a [dialog](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm) rather than a Tkinter Tk main window? It is more appropriate for a simple popup question for user interaction.

Comment: scotty3785 thanks for answer me. Right now I am using simpledialog, however, I have to ask the question one at a time for each pop-up instead one pop-up for a full list of questions. I am going to take a look a dialog. Tnks

Answer (score 0):

You are calling .get(), immediately after creation.
What you are supposed to do is, make it dynamic. Thus, create a button that dynamically checks for the value of the entry when you click it:

```
Check=Button(root, text = "Check",  command =lambda:print(NC_Int.get()))
Check.grid()
```

In the above, I have printed a value. You can call whatever function you want, in which you call "NC_Int.get()".

Hope this helps..